# How to change Chrome's search keyboard shortcut (Ctrl +F)

Tags: google-chrome, keyboard-shortcuts

I would like to change Chrome's default page search keyboard shortcut (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd>) to something else (e.g <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>M</kbd>).

How can I do this?

There is a [Shortcut Manager](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/shortcut-manager/mgjjeipcdnnjhgodgjpfkffcejoljijf) Chrome extension, but it doesn't seem to have an option for search.

Comment: The 'Browser action:' dropdown doesn't have a 'Find' option. Have you tried it yourself?

Comment: I remember, but for some reason I don't have the 'Find' option..